# add function is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

my code is----
what happening is url and id is passed from one function to another but when i clicked on link which contain add(){} function it

```
<a href="#" style="color:#FFF;"onclick="add();" id="cricket" tabindex="1" name="cricket">cricket</a>
```

it doesn't catch the url and id 
javascript fn is-------

```
var url, id;
  function addElement(url,id) {
    //alert(url);
var url1=url;
var id1=id;
   var  main= document.getElementById('mainwidget'); 
   main.innerHTML = "<iframe src="+url+" align='left' height='1060px' width='576px' scrolling='no'  frameborder='0' id='lodex'></iframe>";
    //addUrl(url,id)

 } 

function add(url1,id1){
    alert("ABC"+"     "+url1);
    //addUrl(url,id);
//alert("url"+url);
var append=document.getElementById("addWidgtList");
//alert(append);
    var new_element = append.createElement('li');
    //  alert(new_element);
new_element.innerHTML=("<a href='#' onclick='add("+url+");' id='cricket' name='cricket'>"+id+"</a>");

}
```

Please Help...
Thanks

Comment: When posting code, please use the 101010 button to make it look like code, and then check the preview before posting.

Comment: ok not a problem but what is the solution

Comment: In onclick="add();" option, why you didn't pass any variable in that?

Comment: what i want exactly is when i clicked on first link it must go to first function and that url and id to another function named add(){} when i click on button which contain onclick="add();" function that must contain url from addElement(){} i.e. url and id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

... href="#" style="color:#FFF;"onclick="add(this.url,this.id);" id="cricket" tabindex="1" name="cricket" url="put your URL here">cricket